# How to use implode with mysqli_real_escape_string together

Tags: php, mysqli, implode

How to use implode  with mysqli_real_escape_string together

Correct this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$impdates = implode('<br>',
mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['impdates']));

}
```

Comment: you DON'T use mysqli_real_escape_string at all

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You should be using parameterized prepared statements already.